# SQL command to compare results is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the code on below working and bringing back the OEMPartNumber. My problem is the OEMSubNumber. AS you can see in the table I cannot match the OEMSubNumber like i did the in sql i got working. I have to match the OEMSubNumber to OEMPartNumber then back to OEM Item.. How can i do this?

sql that is working

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.AMIPartNumber = c.Item 
FROM imports as a 
INNER JOIN jdsubs as b 
ON a.OEMPartNumber = b.OEMPartNumber 
INNER JOIN amipartnumbers as c 
ON b.OEMPartNumber = c.OEMItem
```

This is my table layouts

```
imports
----------------
OEMPartNumber  | AMIPartNumber
AR77530        |
AR12345        |

JDSubs
---------------------------
OEMPartNumer    | OEMSubNumber
AR65123         | AR77530
AR12345         | AR56242

AMI
---------------------------
Item            | OEMItem   | Description
AMAR65123       | AR65123   | Axle
AMAR56242       | AR12345   | Spindle
```

UPDATE

I got this working great!

```
UPDATE imports
SET imports.AMIPartNumber = coalesce(apn.Item,asn.Item)
FROM imports as I 
LEFT JOIN jdsubs as PN          ON I.OEMPartNumber = PN.OEMPartNumer 
LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers as APN ON PN.OEMPartNumer = APN.OEMItem 
LEFT JOIN jdsubs as SN          ON I.OEMPartNumber = SN.OEMSubNumber 
LEFT JOIN amipartnumbers as ASN ON SN.OEMPartNumer = ASN.OEMItem
;

select
*
from imports
```

Comment: Your update syntax is wrong, that's all. SQL Server's update via join does not work the same way as Access.

Comment: How do i make it right?

Comment: Did you look at the duplicate?

Comment: i was trying another approach and think i got it. how does this look? UPDATE a SET a.AMIPartNumber =b.OEMPartNumber FROM imports as a INNER JOIN jdsubs as b ON a.OEMPartNumber = b.OEMPartNumber INNER JOIN amipartnumbers as c  ON b.OEMPartNumber = a.OEMPartNumber

Comment: i tried this but it gives me he oem number and not the ami number UPDATE a
SET a.AMIPartNumber =c.Item
FROM imports as a
INNER JOIN jdsubs as b
ON a.OEMPartNumber = b.OEMPartNumber
INNER JOIN amipartnumbers as c
ON a.OEMPartNumber = c.Item

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a duplicate question. This is unique. I have the code on next comment working and bringing back the OEMPartNumber. My problem is the OEMSubNumber. AS you can see in the table I cannot match the OEMSubNumber like i did the in sql i got working. I have to match the OEMSubNumber to OEMPartNumber then back to OEM Item.. How can i do this?

Comment: UPDATE a 
SET a.AMIPartNumber = c.Item 
FROM imports as a 
INNER JOIN jdsubs as b 
ON a.OEMPartNumber = b.OEMPartNumber 
INNER JOIN amipartnumbers as c 
ON b.OEMPartNumber = c.OEMItem

Comment: This is not **unique** just because the linked duplicate doesn't answer your question without any effort on your part to read and understand the answer.  You may have to read and comprehend SQL to get there but it will be worth it in the long run.

Comment: Ok, i understand. Sorry for posting a duplicate and ill do more research. I just thought i could ask and someone could easily answer.

Comment: @AddieAnd-MicaraBaker you've been pointed to a solution that if read and considered careully will solve your problem. It may not be the exact code that you are running but apply the same concepts and you'll be fine.

Comment: k. thanks Zane. I looked at it before but ill look at again.

Comment: i got it done with this query, but it take a lot longer with the OR statements. UPDATE a 
SET a.AMIPartNumber = c.Item 
FROM imports as a 
INNER JOIN jdsubs as b 
ON a.OEMPartNumber = b.OEMsubnumber 
OR a.OEMPartNumber = b.OEMPartNumber 
INNER JOIN amipartnumbers as c 
ON b.OEMPartNumber = c.OEMItem 
OR b.OEMsubnumber = c.OEMItem

Comment: Posted my solution in the original question. There would have been no way i could have derived at that from the "duplicate" question provided